# Completing the square to decompose quadratic forms in three variables

Tags: real-analysis, quadratic-forms

Given the quadratic form $Q(\textbf{x}) = x^2 + 2xy - 4xz +2yz -4z^2$, the question asks to decompose $Q$ into sums of squares, first by eliminating terms in $z$, then terms in $y$, and then terms in $x$.

I know the signature of $Q$ is $(2,1)$ from the solution, but I'm at a loss for how to actually perform what the question is asking. For instance, I recognize that I can take the terms in $x$ and $z$ and form $(x-2z)^2$, but I don't really see what to do next. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a typo? $(x-2z)^2$ doesn't give $-4z^2.$

Answer (score -1):

a method. Usually we take the matrix $H$ to be the Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives. In the special case of integer coefficients with all the mixed coefficent terms even, we can get $H$ all integers by taking half the Hessian matrix.

Outcome this time:

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 3 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 - 2 & 1 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 &  - 3 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 - 2 & 1 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

It is the diagonal elements of $D$ and the rows of $Q$ that give the expression,
$$ \color{red}{ (x+y-2z)^2 - (y-3z)^2 + z^2 } $$

Algorithm discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 - 2 & 1 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 - 2 & 1 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 &  - 2 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 3 \\ 
 - 2 & 3 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 3 \\ 
0 & 3 &  - 8 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 3 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 - 2 & 1 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 1 & 3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 &  - 3 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 &  - 2 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
 - 2 & 1 &  - 4 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$